# Do multimeters take into account their own internal resistance?

Tags: multimeter

When considering sources of error for an experiment measuring the resistivity of a length of wire, the internal resistance of the multimeter I used to measure the resistance came to mind. Would this be accounted for by the multimeter or be a legitimate source of error?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: They do not. You use meters with Kelvin (4-point) probes for that which a dedicated ohmmeter, especially a milliohmeter will have.

Comment: Multimeters are not very accurate at low resistance (<1 ohm) anyway, because the current is about 20 mA. A meter with kelvin probes supplying a higher current will be more accurate.

Comment: Some multimeters (like one or two of mine) allow you to short the leads and then ask them to take an offset reading which is stored into memory for that gain setting. Some analog multimeters also have a potentiometer that you can use to center the needle (hopefully with a mirror behind it) for any given range setting. These can remove the offset to a degree. But the gain error will still be present.

Comment: Most wires also have a fairly substantial temperature coefficient (except for alloys specifically formulated to have a low temperature coefficient). Copper and a lot of other metals go up by about 4 percent for every 10 degrees C.

Comment: Copper also has a low resistance. So typically, to measure the resistance, you have to put a sizeable current through it and then measure the voltage drop caused by the current (Kelvin or 4 wire measurement). But this high current, if it is TOO high, may tend to heat the wire, leading to a change in resistance.

Comment: When really good precision is needed, you have to know the temperature of the wire, and let the current persist long enough for the temperature to be stable. Or read the voltage very quickly before the wire has a chance to heat up.

Comment: Are you talking about the internal resistance of the multimeter or of the leads? The internal one is very high and it's compensated in calibration but the leads are not, usually. For really low (or very high!) resistance measurements there are dedicated instruments. You'll want to look in a microohmeter (often used for windings); it's not cheap however

Answer (score 7):

Meters do not take into account lead resistance, unless they have a ‘nulling’ function like @jonk ‘s fancy meter, or it’s an even fancier 4-lead Kelvin type. This added lead resistance must be characterized prior to measurement and subtracted from the reading.

That said, lead resistance is only significant in the lowest ranges (20 ohm range or less). Lead resistance is normally about 0.2 ohms per lead.

More here: https://www.keysight.com/us/en/lib/resources/training-materials/tip-1-removing-errors-due-to-lead-resistance-372787.html

Answer (score 3):

Most multimeters have a pretty nominal accuracy when measuring resistances down in the ohms. Not only do they not explicitly take account of their lead resistances, but they have small offsets in the measurement of the voltage across the device under test, that means the reported resistance might be plus or minus a few ohms.

Part of the resistance measured will be the **contact** resistance between leads and device, which is variable at the sub-ohm level. Part of the voltage measured will be thermoelectric effects at both ends of both leads where dissimilar metals contact.

When using a cheap meter, I always do a zero resistance calibration by touching the leads together and remebering the result. I do this several times, to get an estimate of the changing contact resistance.

If you want reliable measurements in the ohms region, then you must use a 4-wire technique. This avoids contributions from the leads and from contact resistance, leaving you only thermal voltages to mess up your readings. Note that you don't need a fancy 4-lead meter to do this, just use a 4-lead technique. You can use two meters, or a stable current source and one meter, to measure the current through the device, and the voltage across just the device, without including the voltage across the leads or contact resistances in the measurement. My bench power supply conveniently has a 1 A to 4 A constant current limit, so with a meter reading to mV, I can read mΩs